# google cloud source repositories are not in sync

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos, google-cloud-repository

I'm new to google cloud source repository and confused to why code pushed in one of the repository is not syncing up with another repository. is it because all of the cloud repos need to be connected to same git-lab/git-hub repository? or am i missing something else with respect to sync of code across repository's.

I have 2 repository's namely DEV and QA. pushed my code in DEV and not able to see any of the pushed code in QA repository. as of now both are not connected to any git-lab/git-hub repository, as i can see it in the setting of the cloud repository.

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail about what you've tried and what you're expecting, but repositories are generally independent of one another. Are you looking for the code you pushed to the DEV repository to also be available in the QA repository? If so, that isn't how git repositories (including those hosted by GitHub and GitLab) typically work without some kind of automation.

Comment: @ezkl yes, what you said in the latter part is what I am trying to understand. I had doubt if connecting the cloud repositories to the github/gitlab would do the automation of syncing the code across all repos or if there is other workaround to it. But, as you have informed, I would need some kind of automation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting @ezkl's comment as a Community wiki for better visibility.

If you are looking for the code you pushed to one repository to also be available in another repository, that isn't how git repositories work.

To achieve this goal you would need an automation.

There are some out of the box tools that might be useful:

- [Push code from an existing repository on your local machine to Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/pushing-code-from-a-repository)
- [Mirroring of GitHub or Bitbucket repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-repositories)
- [Add a Google Cloud repository as a remote to a local Git repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes)